# Why the sizeof(D) increased by 8 bytes in VS2015 when I derived D from a virtual base?

Tags: c++, alignment, c++14, virtual-inheritance

I'm using the example in C++14 §3.11/2:

```
struct B { long double d; };
struct D : virtual B { char c; }
```

After running the snippet below in clang, g++ and VS2015

```
#include <iostream>
struct B { long double d; };
struct D : /*virtual*/ B { char c; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(long double) = " << sizeof(long double) << '\n';
    std::cout << "alignof(long double) = " << alignof(long double) << '\n';

    std::cout << "sizeof(B) = " << sizeof(B) << '\n';
    std::cout << "alignof(B) = " << alignof(B) << '\n';

    std::cout << "sizeof(D) = " << sizeof(D) << '\n';
    std::cout << "alignof(D) = " << alignof(D) << '\n';
}
```

I got the following results:

```
                         clang           g++         VS2015  
sizeof(long double)        16             16            8
alignof(long double)       16             16            8
sizeof(B)                  16             16            8
alignof(B)                 16             16            8
sizeof(D)                  32             32           16
alignof(D)                 16             16            8
```

Now, after uncommenting the `virtual` in the definition of `struct D` in the code above and running the code again for clang, g++ and VS2015, I obtained the following results:

```
                         clang           g++         VS2015  
sizeof(long double)        16             16            8
alignof(long double)       16             16            8
sizeof(B)                  16             16            8
alignof(B)                 16             16            8
sizeof(D)                  32             32           24
alignof(D)                 16             16            8
```

I have no doubts about the results obtained above, with one single exception: why did the `sizeof(D)` increased from 16 to 24 in VS2015?

I know this is implementation defined, but there might be a reasonable explanation for this increase in size. This is what I'd like to know if possible.

Comment: @NathanOliver these structs don't have virtual functions. Is vtable created when you virtually derive?

Comment: Just ask the compiler to tell you, use the `/d1reportAllClassLayout` compile option.  You see 8 bytes for the virtual base table pointer + 1 byte for D::c + 7 bytes padding + 8 bytes for B::d == 24.  The pointer is optimized away in the non-virtual case.

Comment: I think this [blog post](http://lolengine.net/blog/2012/10/21/the-stolen-bytes) helps you. In the comment, jangray, who wrote MSVC compiler in a past, gives an explanation.

Comment: @akakatak that interesting blog post describes a totally different problem (different reason space is wasted).  In this case, there is a vtable pointer where it is unclear why a vtable pointer would be required.  In that blog post, the vtable pointer requirement is clear but then excess padding is introduced.

Comment: @Alex GCC uses a virtual table, following the Titanium ABI. Visual C++ uses an internal pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually make use of the virtual aspect of virtual inheritance, I think the need for the vtable pointer becomes clear.  One item in the vtable is likely the offset of the start of `B` from the start of `D`.

Assume `E` inherits virtually from `B` and `F` inherits from both `E` and `D` such that the `D` inside an `F` ends up using the `B` inside the `E` for its base class.  In a method of `D` that doesn't know it is a base class of `F` how could you find members of `B` without info stored in the vtable?

So clang and G++ changed 8 bytes of padding into a vtable pointer and you thought there was no change.  But VS2015 never had that padding, so it needed to add 8 bytes for vtable pointer.

Maybe a compiler notices that the only use of the vtable pointer is in an inefficient scheme for computing the base pointer.  So maybe that is optimized into simply having a base pointer instead of a vtable pointer.  But that would not change the need for the 8 bytes.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable answer: `So clang and G++ changed 8 bytes of padding into a vtable pointer and you thought there was no change. But VS2015 never had that padding, so it needed to add 8 bytes for vtable pointer.`. Thanks (+1).

Comment: I think most people seeing the question would think it meant "why does virtual inheritance without virtual functions need something taking the space a vtable pointer normally takes".  So I think the part you see as the "answer" is for most people just a clarification of the connection between the answer and some details inside the question's example.  I'm glad you got **your** answer, but if you are suggesting pruning down to just that, I think not.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a `virtual` base object, the location of the base object relative to the address of a derived object is not statically predictable. Notably, if you extend your class hierarchy a bit it becomes clear that there can be multiple `D` subobjects which still need to reference just one `B` base object:

```
class I1: public D {};
class I2: public D {};
class Most: public I1, public I2 {};
```

You can get a `D*` from a `Most` object by either converting first to `I1` or first to `I2`:

```
Most m;
D*   d1 = static_cast<I1*>(&m);
D*   d2 = static_cast<I2*>(&m);
```

You'll have `d1 != d2`, i.e., there are genuinely two `D` subobjects, but `static_cast<B*>(d1) == static_cast<B*>(d2)`, i.e., there is just one `B` subobject. To determine how to adjust `d1` and `d2` to find a pointer to the `B` subobject a dynamic offset is needed. The information on how to determine this offset needs to be stored somewhere. The storage for this information is the likely source of the extra 8 bytes.

I don't think the object layout for types in MSVC++ is [publicly] documented, i.e., it is impossible to tell for sure what they are doing. From the looks of it they embed a 64 bit object to be able to tell where the base object lives relative to the address of the derived object (a pointer to some type information, a pointer to a base, an offset to the base, something like that). The other 8 byte most likely originate from the need to store a `char` plus some padding to have the object aligned at a suitable boundary. That seems similar to what the other two compilers do except that they used 16 bytes for `long double` to start with (probably it is just 10 bytes padded to a suitable alignment).

To understand how the C++ object model could work, you might want to have a look at Stan Lippman's ["Inside the C++ Object Model"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Inside-C-Object-Model/dp/0201834545). It is a bit dated but describes potential implementation techniques. Whether MSVC++ uses any of them I don't know but it gives ideas what might be used.

For the object model used by [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) you can have a look at the [Itanium ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html): they essentially use the Itanium ABI with the minor adjustments to the actually used CPU.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, the default behaviour is that all structs are aligned along a 8 byte boundary. i.e.even if you do

```
struct A {
  char c;
}
```

and then check `sizeof(A)`, you will see that it is 8 bytes.

Now, in your case, when you changed the type of inheritance of struct D to be virtual, the compiler has to do something extra to accomplish this. First, it creates a virtual table for the struct D. What does this vtable contain? It contains a single pointer to the offset of struct B in memory.Next, it adds a vptr at the head of struct D which points to the newly created vtable.

Hence, now struct D should look like:

```
 struct D : virtual B { void* vptr; char c; }
```

So, the size of D  will be:

```
sizeof (long double) + sizeof (void*) +  sizeof (char) = 8 + 8 + 1 = 17
```

This is where the boundary alignment we discussed in the beginning comes in. Since all structs have to be aligned to an 8 byte boundary and struct D is only 17 bytes, the compiler adds 7 padding bytes to the struct to make it aligned to a 8 byte boundary.

So the size now becomes:

```
Size of D = Size of elements of D  + Padding bytes for byte alignment = 17 + 7 = 24 bytes.
```

Comment: `In visual studio, the default behaviour is that all structs are aligned along a 8 byte boundary. i.e.even if you do struct A { char c; } and then check sizeof(A), you will see that it is 8 bytes.` [That doesn't seem to be correct.](http://rextester.com/TOJ63653)